# Do the benefits of going second in Yu-Gi-Oh! outweigh those of going first?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I currently have YuGiOh Duel Generation. Recently, I have noticed that some characters prefer to go first. Why would one do this?

If you go second:

- You get to attack first
- You get to draw another card

If you go first:

- You get a lead in development

Do the benefits of going second outweigh going first, or does development really mean so much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one reason is because they are computer characters, thus they were programmed that way. But your question goes beyond that.

> Obviously, the benefits of going second outweighs going first, or does development really mean so much?

This will depend on **the type of deck  and strategy you play.**

But generally speaking, many decks (specially control or combo decks) prefer to go first, as this gives them a **head start in development**, as you pointed out. In the current format this is perhaps **more favorable compared to one extra card or attacking first** turn.

Now days **one card is not as big a difference as some years ago**; it is now not so greater advantage, **as *many* cards now have abilities to search or special summon**.

Also, following a greedy strategy by attacking on first turn may not be such a good idea (by that I mean go all in, not greed as in avarice). As your opponent had lead in development surely some nasty traps or effects await you, thus **attacking first is also not such a great advantage anymore**.

Another aspect is that some decks "need" to go second/first, as per an intrinsic or key part of their strategy. Say you play a [Lava Golem](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Lava_Golem) deck, you will need a monster on your Opp side to play your Lava Golem, so going first may not be such a great idea. Or say you play some control deck, or play with [Traptrix](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Traptrix). In that case you surely want to start to lay out your traps and control mechanisms ASAP.

*So, to sum it up*: in the current format starting with one card or attacking first is less advantageous than before (now many cards search from deck or special summon), except for those decks whose strategy *requires* or benefits from going second.

Comment: This is more an answer to "Compare going first to second"; You have not specifically answered my question.

Comment: @VortexYT :0 I even quoted your question, what other one did I miss? The one on the title? That one was also answered in my post, please clarify so I can edit

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you did answer it but only partially

Comment: I would've liked an explanation on the key pts I made. You didn't talk about drawing an extra card or any other pts I missed

Comment: However this is not your fault for I didn't specifically say

Comment: @VortexYT uhmmm... please read my answer again, as I did mention those things (extra card, attack, lead development). I'll enhance my answer in a while if I come up with new things to add.

Comment: Please explain to me where? I may have misread, but I don't think you did

Comment: "Now days one card is not as big a difference as some years ago; it is now not so greater advantage, as many cards now have abilities to search or special summon. ", or "Also, following a greedy strategy by attacking on first turn may not be such a good idea...", or "Some decks (usually control or combo decks) prefer to go first..."

Comment: How does that explain the draw one card?

Comment: I've accepted and up voted, but I'm still quite unsure what you have talked about. It isn't as clear as I would like it to be

Comment: And I apologise about how pedantic I am

Comment: @VortexYT haha no problem, edited my answer in the hopes of better readability and clarity.